# Html.EditorFor throws property not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting an odd error from an MVC3 webforms view that has stumped me.

Setup:
I have two interfaces defined:

```
public interface IDbObject {
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IAutomobile : IDbObject { 
  string VIN { get; set; }
}

public class Automobile : IAutomobile {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string VIN { get; set; }
}
```

My view is a strongly-typed view: `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IAutomobile>`  and my controller

When I attempt to use a EditorFor on the Name property

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(a => a.Name) %>
```

I get an exception:  **System.ArgumentException: The property IAutomobile.Name could not be found.**

However, if I comment out this statement, my EditorFor on the VIN continues to function properly:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(a => a.VIN) %>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

I re-implemented the 'Name' property on the IAutomobile interface:

```
public interface IAutomobile : IDbObject { 
  new string Name { get; set; }
  string VIN { get; set; }
}
```

I made no changes to my concrete class, and the EditorFor method was able to work with the Name property.

Comment: I have a feeling that this might result in problems when using your objects as `IDbObject`s.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a limitation of `EditorFor`. Perhaps it's not smart enough to check implemented interfaces for properties.

Comment: It looks like it is not checking the implemented interface.  I think I found my solution

Comment: Actually, this error isn't from the EditorFor but from the AssociatedMetadataProvider

Comment: Hmm, I actually think that this might count a bug for the AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider class.